# airflow configure mail template

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create a mail template for my dags in airflow, 
I'm strugling to find the documentation, I tried [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html) but it's poor
I'm trying to find out what are the variables that I could use in my template, for example :
 for the subject I want to access the dag name (not the `{{ ti }}` which contains others informations), also for the body, I want to choose which part to be send (in my case, the real exception is displayed as warning in aiflow log, thus, I want to send it instead of `{{ exception_html }}`

Comment: Since you have added a google-cloud-composer tag in your question , are you running this application on GCP composer ?

Comment: yes I'm using composer and airflow2

Comment: Could you share some reproducible code to replicate your setup?